# Gauge transformation as transition functions?

Tags: differential-geometry, gauge-theory, topology

I understand that transition functions are between different patches $U_i, U_j$, i.e. in $U_i\cap U_j$ you need a transition function to stitch local trivializations.

On the other hand, gauge transformations are *not* between different patches, it is a bundle automorphism.

So how does one view gauge transformation as transition functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way you can *locally* view diffeomorphisms as coordinate changes.

Let $\pi: P\rightarrow M$ be a principal $G$-bundle. As it is well-known, for a PFB, local trivializations and local sections are the same.

Suppose first that $P=M\times G$ is trivial, the right action being given by (for $p=(x,g)$) $ph=(x,gh)$. Let $f:P\rightarrow P$ be a vertical automorphism. Then$$ f(x,g)=(x,q(x,g)) $$ for some function $q:P\rightarrow G$ and the automorphism property we have $$ f(x,g)=f(x,eg)=f(x,e)g=(x,q(x,e))g=(x,q(x,e)g), $$so the most general vertical automorphism of the product PFB is specified by a $G$-valued function $\varphi:M\rightarrow G$ such that $$ f(x,g)=(x,\varphi(x)g). $$

---

Now let $P$ be an in general nontrivial PFB, $(U,\sigma)$ a local section over $U\subseteq M$, $P_U=\pi^{-1}(U)$ the PFB restricted to $U$.

**Proposition:** There is a bijective correspondance between local sections $(U,\sigma^\prime)$ (with the same domain $U$) and vertical automorphisms $f\in\mathrm{Aut}_V(P_U)$.

*Proof:* First let a local section $(U,\sigma^\prime)$ be given, then there is a unique $G$-valued function $\varphi:U\rightarrow G$ given by $\sigma^\prime(x)=\sigma(x)\varphi(x)$. Since $(U,\sigma)$ is equivalent to a local trivialization, it gives an isomorphism $P_U\cong U\times G$ mapping $p$ to $(x,g)$, where $x=\pi(p)$ and $g$ is given by $p=\sigma(x)g$. Now define $f:P_U\rightarrow P_U$ by $f(p)=f(x,g)=(x,\varphi(x)g)$, where we made use of the identification $P_U\cong U\times G$.

Conversely, any vertical automorphism $f:P_U\rightarrow P_U$ uniquely determines the $G$-valued function $\varphi:U\rightarrow G$ by $f(x,g)=(x,\varphi(x)g)$ and then we can use $\varphi$ do define a new local section $(U,\sigma^\prime)$ by $\sigma^\prime(x)=\sigma(x)\varphi(x)$. Clearly then $\varphi$ is the transition function between these local sections. Clearly, these two constructions are inverses of one another.

Hence we have $\{\text{Local sections over $U$}\}\cong\{\text{Vertical automorphisms over $U$}\}$ as long as we have fixed one local section $(U,\sigma)$ over $U$.

This establishes the *local* equivalence between gauge transformations (physics style, i.e. transition functions) and gauge transformations (mathematics style, i.e. vertical automorphisms).

Comment: I think I understood your answer. Thank you very much. Although, my question was rather regarding "different patches" and "on the same patch". (clearly, I didn't ask the question well), i.e. the transition function exists on the intersection of two patches (each has a local section and the transition stitches them); while gauge transformation is on ONE local patch.

Comment: @Alex In very physics-y physics texts, the local-global problems are completely ignored usually. This effectively means that we are always working whenever the patches overlap. So a gauge trf (physics-y) is always between two patches which may or may not coincide. But if there is a nonzero overlap, we may always restrict to the common overlap and then we have a gauge trf between two completely coinciding patches.

Comment: @Alex It should also be noted that a gauge trf is always only defined on the overlap even if we don't ignore the rest of the domains, i.e. if $(U,\sigma)$ and $(V,\tau)$ are two local sections, then the transition function/gauge trf between the two is a $G$-valued function $\varphi:U\cap V\rightarrow G$ defined only on the overlaps. Then this is equivalent to a vertical automorphism on $P_{U\cap V}=\pi^{-1}(U\cap V)$ up to a preferred choice of gauge on $U\cap V$.